# Wordpress New Pages and Posts not showing for public users (IIS 8)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iis-8

**Hello Everyone**
I have a really weird issue on a WordPress website running on IIS 8 server, I'm still a beginner in IIS so the issue could be something stupid, the issue is when I do create any new page or post in WordPress I can see the page working fine in the admin dashboard but if not logging the page give me as the screen below and also the mixed content warning  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6qjq.png)

i had tryied many thinks such give permission to IUSER and i had try all the SSL plugins fixer i did check the code of the theme also but with no results , please if any one can help this issue is really frustrating

Comment: First I don't think the server type matter, in this case, this is the WordPress internal system. The cache plugins can do this very easily.  The page is giving "This wasn't something that we expected" message. I have tried a non-exist URL and I go the same error so I belive that the page is returning a 404 error in that page.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you have any special permission plugins? Cache plugins?

Comment: So it could be caused by a plugin

Comment: yes I have a 404 to 301 - Redirect, Log and Notify 404 Errors Plugin could that  cause the issue

Comment: Naturally, WordPress posts are visible the moment you publish them. If they don't it's either a cache plugin that won't show your post until the cache is reloaded or a plugin that is doing special rules.

Comment: I'll try to deactivate all the plugins and enable them one by one, or there is any other method to detect the issue

Comment: You can use F12 to check whether there is any error in the content of NetWork. If there is, you should solve the problem according to the error.

Comment: I did all those recommendations nothing works, also I did give permissions to users and everything but still the same issue

Comment: please view the error in the content of NetWork use F12.